# In Java is there any way to share memory location to exchange some real-time small packets?

Tags: java, linux, real-time

Is there any better/smarter way to `put` and `get` a boolean value from `memory system`, but not using any `TCP/UDP` nor `local file system` method?

```
For example:

#both running as 1 application separately

$ java -cp /var/tmp/J.jar System.Backend

$ java -cp /var/tmp/J.jar System.Frontend
```

Where `Backend` does memory allocation, and Frontend reads it on the fly, none of them will be able to use TCP/UDP nor File system.

Comment: so no PipedInputsstream?

Comment: maybe these could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125534/what-is-the-best-way-to-access-memory-in-java-similar-to-mmap http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1491519/any-concept-of-shared-memory-in-java and http://www.coderanch.com/t/441876/java/java/does-java-support-shared-memory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, The only way to use shared memory in pure Java is to use memory mapped files.

If you want two pieces of code to share memory, the simplest thing to do is to use one JVM. There is rarely a good reason to use more than one JVM with tightly couple code.

Answer (score 1):

If you can make one application to launch another via Process API, then they can communicate over standard input an output.