# Fastest IPC between a Java and C++ process

Tags: java, c++, ipc

Assumption: both are running on the same box.

What's the recommendation out of the whole set of options available?

Speed and reliability are the two spots the solution should hit.

Comment: The question is too vague to answer. Without knowing what data you want to communicate, what direction it goes, how often it needs to be sent, how big it is, and so on, there's no "one right answer".

Comment: Also, since speed seems to be kind of important to you, you should perhaps elaborate what OS, a description of the box and the specific type of data that needs to be communicated.

Comment: Duplicate of

 - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/165945/what-is-the-best-approach-for-ipc-between-java-and-c
 - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125534/what-is-the-best-way-to-access-memory-in-java-similar-to-mmap

Sounds like a job for `ByteBuffer.allocateDirect()`

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a task well-suited for sockets.